# Value of ng-model undefined in custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am writing a custom directive which calls a legacy javascript date control we are using in other places.. The issue I am facing is the value of the `ng-model` I send in is always undefined.

This value is coming from a `$http.get` which is executed in the controller. The code for the directive seems to be hit before the controller code is run which is why this is happening. Is there a way for me to tell the directive only to run after the controller has been initialized?

```
app.directive('dateControl', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '^ngModel',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            // scope.ngModel is undefined in here
            alert(scope.ngModel);
            addCalControlAngular(attr.id, scope.ngModel, attr.ngModel, attr.id);
        }
    }
});


<td date-Control ng-model="postAward.letterOfAwardDespatchDate" id="letterofaward">
```

Comment: Where is the rest? Also, try to make a fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this with a $watch in my link function

```
link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            debugger;
            // Watch for a value in ngModel and render that value, otherwise give a default
            scope.$watch('ngModel', function (newVal) {
                if (newVal) {
                    addCalControlAngular(attr.id, scope.ngModel, attr.isMandatory, attr.showDefault, attr.ngModel, attr.id);
                } else {
                    addCalControlAngular(attr.id, c_NULL_DATE, attr.isMandatory, attr.showDefault, attr.ngModel, attr.id);
                }
            })            
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

The directive is not 'hit' before controller if it's inside controller, but if the value comes from http request then it's undefined until the model is updated with value (hope that makes sense), to assure that directive is executed after receiving data from http you can do a small trick with `ng-if`

```
<td procon-Date-Control ng-if="postAward.letterOfAwardDespatchDate" ng-model="postAward.letterOfAwardDespatchDate" id="letterofaward">
```

If you do it that way directive is going to be rendered in view only of the `ng-if` is not null/undefined or the expression is truthy i.e. ng-if="postAward.letterOfAwardDespatchDate == 'yesterday'"

Comment: great- that works well. In this case though since I'm rendering a date control, how is it best to handle if there is nothing there in the model?

Comment: using this, the directive will only ever be displayed if there is value in the model.. am I right?

Comment: unfortunately this will not solve the issue then.. Is there a way to resolve a promise created in a controller from inside a directive?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use `ngModel` try to add a argument in link function to add a injection like this:

```
link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModel)
```

After this, you can use code like `ngModel.$render` and so on, hope that helpful to you.

Comment: How about if I rename the attribute ngModel to myNgModel, is it OK or ngModel (ng-model) attribute is mandatory to name like that in custom directive?

Comment: link takes a function with the following signature, function link(scope, element, attrs, controller, transcludeFn) { ... }, where:

scope is an Angular scope object.
element is the jqLite-wrapped element that this directive matches.
attrs is a hash object with key-value pairs of normalized attribute names and their corresponding attribute values.
controller is the directive's required controller instance(s) or its own controller (if any). The exact value depends on the directive's require property.
transcludeFn is a transclude linking function pre-bound to the correct transclusion scope.